# Bootstrap collapsed menu not displaying with google map

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I have a webpage which has a bootstrap navbar and a google map. navbar is fixed on top and the google map is placed so that to fill the rest of the screen

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <header class="row">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="brand" href="#">{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png', array('class'=>'logo')) }}</a>
       </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reports <b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Report 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Report 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Report 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Report 4</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User <b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="main">
    <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
</div>
</div>`
```

There is no problem with the loading of google maps and the navbar. But when the nav bar is collapsed and I am clicking the toggle button the menu is not getting displayed.

CSS:

```
html,body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;}

#mapcanvas {
display: block;
position:absolute;
height:auto;
bottom:0;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin-top:50px;
}
```

Bootply : [bootply.com/3ejKtiSHkw](http://www.bootply.com/3ejKtiSHkw)

Comment: can u provide a fiddle, or bootply, so that we can have a closer look as the code seems to be fine to me so far...

Comment: @nozzleman Updated the question. Here is Bootply link bootply.com/3ejKtiSHkw

Comment: i've updated my answer. the important part was missing due to lack of copy-past-skills...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know exactly whats the problem, but ive found out theat it seems to be sth. with the css.

adding the `navbar-fixed-top`-class to your navbar makes the dropdown work. I don't know if thats you required behavior though.

so, to break it down:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

makes the dropdowns work in the collapsed navbar.

Comment: EDITED: Im sorry, the essential part was missing ;)